# Add some controls like Textblock as ItemSource in C# code behind

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

I have ArcGIS Windows Runtime Esri project and my XAML is like this:

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">

<esri:MapView.Overlays>
    <esri:OverlayItemsControl>
            <Grid MaxWidth="350">
                <TextBlock Text="Details" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </esri:OverlayItemsControl>
</esri:MapView.Overlays>

</esri:MapView>
```

I want to add this `Overlays` and `OverlayItemsControl` in code behind rather than from XAML.

I have tried somethig like this in C# code behind:

```
MapView mapView = new MapView();
mapView.Overlays.ItemsSource = new List<object> { new TextBlock() { Text = "Details", Name = "overLay" } };
mapView.Overlays.Items.Clear();
mapView.Overlays.Items.Add(MyMapView.Overlays.ItemsSource);
```

But it gives error. I don't know exactly what is wrong here.

How to add those controls `Overlays, Grid, Textblock` from code behind inside that Esri `MapView` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am drawing a textbox at given map point (mp) through the code:

```
TextBox tbMsg = new TextBox();
tbMsg.Width = 250;
tbMsg.Height = 200;
tbMsg.Text = "Your Message";

tbMsg.GotFocus += Tb_GotFocus;
tbMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Controls.MapView.SetViewOverlayAnchor(tbMsg, mp);
MyMapView.Overlays.Items.Add(tbMsg);
```

Comment: Where is the question.

Comment: You cannot add directly over the Esri map control.